# close db connection without breaking existing code

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a function that I need to add code to dispose the opened database connection. 
I am unsure where in the function to add :

```
   dbCommand.Dispose()
    db = Nothing
```

without breaking the code accidentally.

Could I get some help in adding these lines of code to the existent code below?

Thank you.

The code is:

```
Public Shared Function SendAdminEmail() As Boolean
    Dim ipAddress As String = ""
    Try
        ipAddress = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR")
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try

    If (ipAddress > "") Then
        Dim db As Database = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase(Globals.AppSettings("webdb"))
        Dim dbCommand As DbCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand("VerifySendAdminEmail")
        db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@IPAddress", DbType.String, ipAddress)
        Dim ds As DataSet = db.ExecuteDataSet(dbCommand)
        If (Not ds Is Nothing) Then
            If (ds.Tables.Count > 0) Then
                If (ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0) Then
                    If (ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)(0).ToString = "0") Then
                        Return False
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
    Return True
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

If an object uses the IDisposable interface, then you can simply wrap the objects in a using block, which will automatically call the Dispose method for you.  For a database connection, they will close the connection for you, even when you short-circuit the function with an early return call like in your example.

```
Using db As Database = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase(Globals.AppSettings("webdb"))
  Using dbCommand As DbCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand("VerifySendAdminEmail")
    db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@IPAddress", DbType.String, ipAddress)
    Using ds As DataSet = db.ExecuteDataSet(dbCommand)
      If (Not ds Is Nothing) Then
        If (ds.Tables.Count > 0) Then
          If (ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0) Then
            If (ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)(0).ToString = "0") Then
              Return False
            End If
          End If
        End If
      End If
    End Using
  End Using
End Using
```

Comment: Thank you for that information. I did not know that. Question, can the db connections be disposed before the last end if shown in the code I pasted? Sort if like:
            End If
            '20140916/ ANG
            dbCommand.Dispose()
            db = Nothing
        End If
        Return True

Comment: @itortu If you are done using the object, then you can call dispose on that object.  But I don't know why you would avoid using the using block: it's your friend.  It's a good habit to get into.

Comment: I do not know how to get the Using statement to work. I get an error:  using' operand of type 'microsoft.practices.enterpriselibrary.data.database' must implement 'system.idisposable'

Comment: @itortu Then you can't use the Using block on your Database object. It does not implement the interface.  I'm not familiar with that library.  It looks old.